# How to Add changable text on splash screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen

Hi i want to add text on the splash image on splash screen. i have added single text on image but i want to change the text every time the app opens.how to do that please tell me .

i have added single textview in splash.xml it is displaying . But i want to display all the item in the list.xml one-by-one every time app opens.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quote"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your limitation—it's only your imagination."
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="36sp"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

in list.xml

```
<string-array name="quote_array">
    <item>Your limitation—it's only your imagination.</item>
    <item>Great things never come from comfort zones.</item>
    <item>The harder you work for something, the greater you’ll feel when you achieve it.</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Just get the array list inside your splash screen than generate a random number to the size of the array after that set text like arraylist.get(random number).

Comment: Quote.settext(arraylist.get(randomnumber));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a random number and get an item from the array in this random position.

Sample code:

```
TextView quote = findViewById(R.id.quote);
String[] quoteArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quote_array); 

int randomPosition = (int)(Math.random()*(quoteArray.length-1))

quote.setText(quoteArray[randomPosition]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

1. You create a class that extends from AsyncTask:

   ```
   public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
       private String[] stringArray;
       private TextView myTextView;
       private long delay;

       MyAsyncTask(String[] stringArray, long delay, TextView myTextView) {
           this.stringArray = stringArray;
           this.delay = delay;
           this.myTextView = myTextView;
       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
           try {
                for (String value : stringArray) {
                   Thread.sleep(delay);
                   publishProgress(value);
                }
           } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
               // Handle interrupted exception
           }

           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onProgressUpdate(String... value) {
           myTextView.setText(value[0]);
       }
   }
   ```

   This allows you to edit the textview as the code is executed within your thread.
2. Run the asynctask from the activity, passing it by parameters the list of strings, the time in milliseconds you want between text changes and the textview that you want to be modified:

   ```
   TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

   new MyAsyncTask(
           getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quote_array),
           5000,
           myTextView).execute();
   ```

I hope it has been helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If order does not matter you can use random Integer by `new Random.nextInt(stringArray.length() - 1);` each time you start your application. But if you want to show your strings in order from 0 to the last, you need to persist previous index in any storage. I think `SharedPreferences` is better solution for it.

Good luck!